# How to connect with WinAuth to SQL Server without desktop login?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have a username + password from a user in an Active Directory domain.

With this Windows user, I could login to a SQL Server with WinAuth.

However, there is no "desktop" where I could login and identify.

So, how how can I connect to the SQL Server? In fact, I think that I would need to identify somewhere in the Active Directory, then I would get the credentials token, and then I could proceed. But how is that done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Windows Credentials Manager.
Go to Control Panel> Credential Manager> Add a Windows Credential

This will allow you to present the remote network as the stored credentials.

[image]

Some useful links:
[Tutorial on how to do this on Sqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/)
[Answer on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66014/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-in-a-different-domain)

Comment: Thank you, that leads closer to the solution! However, when I have stored the credentials, how can I use them in order to connect? Meanwhile, I 've found a solution tio start the ssms with `runas /netonly /user ... ssms.exe` which basically works, but I need to enter the password again. If I could use the stored credentials, than this would be great, but how can I link the stored credentials to a command ?